# Was the scenery in Casper (1995) CGI?

Tags: effects, casper

These days, much of the scenery of movies is CGI, e.g., zooming over gothic estate scenery, zooming around in an old gothic house.  Was this the case in the 1995 Casper movie, or was all of that real and physical (not the ghosts, I'm talking about the interior and exterior scenery, e.g, even the trip down to the subterranean lab)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [**IMDB**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112642/locations?ref_=tt_dt_dt)'s shooting locations list...at least some of it was real.

> Singapore Lake, Backlot, Universal Studios - 100 Universal City Plaza, Universal City, California, USA

[image]

> Stage 28, Universal Studios - 100 Universal City Plaza, Universal City, California, USA
>
> Colonial Mansion, Backlot, Universal Studios - 100 Universal City Plaza, Universal City, California, USA

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I found it hard to tell what was real.  But my confusion is based partly on the fact that scenery CGI these days is very good.  It wasn't as good back then, so I expect that CGI scenery would be easier to recognize.